# Angular validation form

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
     <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" />
        <div ng-show="myForm.myField.$error" style="color: red">
            {{myForm.myField.$error}}
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And i have angular controller

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myForm.myField.$error = "just to see it work";
});
```

Why do I get error '$scope.myForm is undefined'?

Comment: Because form controller is not yet created probably when your controller function is executed. You shouldn't set anything on your form controller directly that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have model, module and controller a little confused. My solutions uses Angular 1.2, although you will soon need to move to Angular 2.
Here is my reworking of your example:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
        <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.myField" name="myField" />
            <div style="color: red">
                {{ctrl.myField}}
            </div>
        </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the controller.js:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
.controller('AppCtrl', [function() {
    this.myField = "just to see it work";
}]);
```

In the above, I have put "myField" in the scope of the controller "AppCtrl". I have put the whole page under the control of the module 'MyApp'. You can either inject the model with "ng-bind" or use the curly bracket notation in the body of the div to bind to the "myField" model of "ctrl". I have used the latter but be aware this binding will be established after the page has been parsed.
If you load this all now, you should see "just see it work" in red under the text field, and also inside the text field. When you edit the text box, the red text will change in sync. Once you have that working, you will never want to stop learning more about Angular!

I should add that this model has a single attribute. To generalise this you will need to create a model with several properties (one for each input element), so that a JSON object is returned when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't have dots in your variable name.**

Try `myFormMyFieldError` instead of `myForm.myField.$error`.

Additional: Rather than using the attribute `style`, use a CSS file.